# Django Using GenericForeignKey to reference a model

Tags: django, models

ok, so my database has a headers/lines type structure, where there is header models which have many lines models. This structure is in place on many models. I want to keep track of which header models are related to which lines models.

Originally I simply had an attribute on the header model pointing to the related models, but would like this to be stored in the database.

So I have used djangos `GenericForeignKey` stuff before, but only when I wanted to have foreign key relationships with several model records, not just the model themselves.

With the `GenericForeignKey` you have three things needed:

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

In my case, I dont need the `object_id` but I dont think that I can leave it out...

So after all that I guess my question is if using `GenericForeignKey` is the best way of setting up this model, or are there any other solutions.

Another thought was just to use the model names...

hopefully that all makes sense. thanks

Comment: If I get your problem right, just having the `ForeignKey` to `ContentType`should be all you need?

Comment: so would that create a field in the database `content_type` and just store the models content type id thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you just want it to point to the models themselves, not individual records, all you need is

```
my_model = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
```

Then, if you want to figure out which model a header is associated with, just do

```
>>> my_header.my_model
<ContentType: Model Name>
```

If you want to point to specific records, you need the other two fields. The object_id field holds the pk of the record you're pointing too. And the content_object field is NOT stored in the database, but rather is just a nice wrapper that (using the object_id and content_type fields) returns the model object, rather than you having to look up the record manually based on the content type and the id.

Comment: I understood that the last field wasnt in the database, but to be honest I didnt really get why. Thanks for the explanation and the great answer